# Bilinear filter in repeating texture, HLSL

Tags: shaders, directx, filtering

I have a repeating texture that I'm using as a scroll surface.  The idea is that as I pan the surface I adjust the texture coordinates, filling in what gets wrapped on the right as it disappears from the left.  This is all working quite well.

When bilinear filtering is switched on (D3DTEXF_LINEAR) I think the repeat filters the edge of the texture with the corresponding pixels on the other side given the wrap.  This is wrong of course.

I've had a look around for bilinear filtering shaders that ignore edge texels but can't seem to find anything.  Does anyone have an ideas about how to do this?  Is there a way of configuring a sampler to ignore edge texels when filtering?  Is there a bilinear filtering shader knocking around I can use as a reference?

Comment: Have you tried setting the texture sampler addressing mode to clamp? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476256(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I do that I'll lose texture repeat, surely?  To be clear, I want repeating textures, but I don't want filtering over the edges.

Comment: Yes, you will lose the scrolling UV functionality.